# Foreign key is null php laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.7

Пытаюсь сделать отношения "один ко многим". У меня есть таблицы users и orders

в модели Users есть такой метод:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::class);
}
```

в ControllerUsers есть такое:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $this->model::create($request->all())->id; // здесь записывается юзер при регистрации после заказов в таблицу users тут все ок

    $arr = []; // сюда записываю заказы которые пользователь сделал и потом зарегистрировался
    foreach ($request->all()['users_data'] as $el) {
        $arr[] = [
            'user_id' => $id,
            'usluga' =>'фытвлфоытволфыв'
        ];
    }
    $Users = new Users();
    $Users->orders()->createMany($arr);

    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

миграция у ordres такая:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('usluga');
    });
}
```

ошибка на такая:

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 'фытвлфоытволфыв'). (SQL: insert into "orders" ("user_id", "usluga") values (, 'фытвлфоытволфыв'))
```

Использую ларавел версии "Laravel Framework 5.7.21"

Что я делаю не так? Почему в `user_id` `null` если в `dd($id)` в методе store точно есть id юзера

В классе Orders в `$fillable` указан `user_id`. 
А в классе Users нет `$fillable`, но есть `$guarded` в котором `user_id` не указан

БД PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому пригодиться. Мне подсказали сделать вот так и это действительной работает в моем случае.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->model::create($request->all());

    $arr = [];
    foreach ($request->all()['users_data'] as $el) {
        $arr[] = [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'usluga' =>'фытвлфоытволфыв'
        ];
    }
    $user->orders()->createMany($arr);

    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```